# Python Pandas add new column which will have multiple columns values along with column names

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently in the process of automating SQL script using the csv file and pandas module. where condition is based on the values present on my csv file.

Sample csv file wll be as below.

```
First   Last
X        A
Y        B
Z        C
```

I want a new dataframe which should look like this(with new column added).

```
First   Last          condition
X        A     First='X' and Last='A'
Y        B     First='Y' and Last='B'
Z        C     First='Z' and Last='C'
```

so i can use the third column in my sql where condition.

Note:
I can achieve this by below method but i cannot use it because my column names are not static, i mean i will be using this on multiple csv/df's which will have different column names, also number columns might be more than 2.

```
df['condition'] = 'First=\'' + df['First'] +'\' And ' + 'Last=\'' + df['Last'] +'\''
```

If I resolve the 'condition' column then my final SQL will should look like this:

```
Select First, Last from mydb.customers
where
(First='X' and Last='A') or
(First='Y' and Last='B') or
(First='Z' and Last='C')
```

Thanks

Comment: So you just want a function that does this?

Comment: `df.columns` gives names of all columns so you can use it with `for` loop.

Comment: @Dmitry Yes it turned out to be a function which I should apply on dataframe as suggested by furas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply` with row (`axis=1`) to execute function with every row - and this functions gets all informations about data in row - column names and values

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'First': ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
        'Second': ['1', '2', '3'],
        'Last': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    })

print(df)

def concatenate(row):
    parts = []

    for name, value in row.items():
        parts.append("{}='{}'".format(name, value))

    return ' and '.join(parts)


df['condition'] = df.apply(concatenate, axis=1)

print(df['condition'])
```

Data:
(because I used dictionary which doesn't have to keep order so I get `Second` as last element ;) )

```
  First Last Second
0     X    A      1
1     Y    B      2
2     Z    C      3
```

Result:

```
0    First='X' and Last='A' and Second='1'
1    First='Y' and Last='B' and Second='2'
2    First='Z' and Last='C' and Second='3'
Name: condition, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi @furas, Thank you for the solution. I have accepted your answer. I am yet to try this but based on your explanation I am sure it works. Once again thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that accomplishes what you are attempting.  This takes any string series (such as yours) and creates the pattern you want with the series name.

Avoiding explicitly naming the columns is the hard part.

```
from functools import reduce  #for python 3, it is native in 2

def series_to_str(s):
    n = s.name
    return n+"='" + s +"'"

df['condition'] = reduce(lambda x, y: x+' and '+y, 
                         map(series_namer, (df[col] for col in df)))
```

Comment: Thank you @James, I will check this solution as well.